Plot with image
I'd like to use an image of Earth in the following plot:
Off[Solve::ifun]
<< MaTeX`;
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{color}"}];
erre[a_, e_, f_] = Divide[a (1 - e^2), 1 + e Cos[f]];
r[a_, e_, f_] = erre[a, e, f] {Cos[f], Sin[f]};
dfdt[a_, e_, \[Mu]_, f_] = Divide[h[a, e, \[Mu]], erre[a, e, f]^2];
V[a_, e_, f_] = Simplify[D[r[a, e, f], f] dfdt[a, e, \[Mu], f]];
Clear[fq]
fq[e_] = f /. 
   Solve[V[a, e, f][[1]]/Sqrt[Simplify[V[a, e, f].V[a, e, f]]] == -1, 
     f][[2]];
h[a_, e_, \[Mu]_] = Sqrt[a \[Mu] (1 - e^2)];
\[Mu] = 398600
R = 6378;
Rp = 1.5 R;
Ra = 6 R;
a = (Ra + Rp)/2
Print["Ecentricidade"]
e = 1 - Rp/a
qp = N[a Sqrt[(1 - e^2)]]
q = N[r[a, e, fq[e]]]
V[a, e, 0]
V[a, e, fq[e]]
V[a, e, Pi]
ParametricPlot[{r[a, e, f][[1]], r[a, e, f][[2]]}, {f, 0, 2 Pi},
 Axes -> False,
 PlotStyle -> Black,
 PlotRange -> {{-(Ra + 0.5 R), Rp + 0.9 R}, {-(qp + 0.55 R), 
    qp + 0.55 R}},
 Ticks -> None,
 Epilog -> {
   {RGBColor[0.46, 0.46, 0.84], Disk[{0, 0}, R]},
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 2 R}}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {2 R, 0}}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, q}],
   {Red, Arrow[{{Rp, 0}, {Rp, Rp/1.0025}}], 
    Arrow[{{-Ra, 0}, {-Ra, -Rp/2}}], 
    Arrow[{q, {q[[1]] - Rp/1.25, q[[2]]}}]},
   {Green, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.2 R, {0, fq[e]}]},
   {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {-Ra, 0}}], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {0, -erre[a, e, 3 Pi/2]}}]},
   {Dashed, Darker[Red], Line[{{q[[1]], 0}, {q[[1]], q[[2]]}}], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {q[[1]], 0}}]},
   {Darker[Cyan], PointSize[Large], Point[q]},
   Inset[MaTeX["\\hat{p}", Magnification -> 1.5], {Rp + 0.7 R, 0}], 
   Inset[MaTeX["\\hat{q}", Magnification -> 1.5], {-0.25 R, 1.9 R}], 
   Inset[MaTeX["B", Magnification -> 1.5], {q[[1]], q[[2]] + 0.3 R}], 
   Inset[MaTeX["{\\color{green}\\theta}", 
     Magnification -> 1.5], {0.875 R, 1.075 R}], 
   Inset[MaTeX["{\\color{red} \\vec{v}}", 
     Magnification -> 1.5], {Rp + 0.3 R, 1.1 R}], 
   Inset[MaTeX["{\\color{red} \\vec{v}}", 
     Magnification -> 1.5], {q[[1]] - 0.9 R, q[[2]] + 0.3 R}], 
   Inset[MaTeX["{\\color{red} \\vec{v}}", 
     Magnification -> 1.5], {-Ra - 0.3 R, -0.8 R}]}
 ]
Clear[R, Rp, Ra, a, e, \[Mu]]

If you run the code, you'll see I just used a blue disk with the RGBColor, instead an image of Earth. However, I really want to use an image. I want to use an image from the internet to represent Earth, instead the blue disk.

I am not sure what you are asking. To save the image to a file, do p=ParametricPlot[...] then use the Export command to save p to image file of your choice.

@Nasser, I know how to save the image. I want to use an image from the internet and use it instead of the blue disk to represent Earth. Sorry if I was not clear.

I suggest that MaTeX isn't the best solution for single characters. Consider OverHat and OverVector instead. You could change MaTeX["\\hat{p}", Magnification -> 1.5] to Style[OverHat["p"], Magnification -> 1.5], etc. This method is faster and eliminates the need for the MaTeX package.

You can use Texture to display an image in the Disk in your plot. As an example, before ParametricPlot, add this Texture expression (note that the texture can be an image in place of this GeoGraphics example):
(* use a resized, smaller image for texture *)
texture = Texture[ImageResize[
  GeoGraphics[GeoCenter -> GeoPosition["NorthPole"], GeoRange -> All,
  GeoProjection -> "Orthographic", GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap"], 128]]


In Epilog, change {RGBColor[0.46, 0.46, 0.84], Disk[{0, 0}, R]} to {texture, Disk[{0, 0}, R]}.

It didn't work :(
Now the planet is completely black

@EricD'Antona Try a smaller image with Texture. I've made a change to reduce the size of the GeoGraphics output.

@EricD'Antona Try Graphics[{texture, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}] to verify that the texture works for you.
